# How to `scl enable devtoolset-8 bash` when login in?

Tags: centos7, devtoolset

In my centos7, I tried to put `scl enable devtoolset-8 bash` command to ~/.bashrc but When I login in, processes of `scl enable devtoolset-8 bash` are started again and again until the process number reaches the user max process number.

So what should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solve it by using `echo "source /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/enable" >> /etc/profile`